# Combination - How many different ways.

Tags: combinatorics

> In how many different ways it is possible to seat 5 women and 5 men in 10 seat spots available where all 5 women seat next to each other?

I'm thinking $6\cdot5!\cdot5!$

6-different spots between the men

5!- for men

5!- for women

Is that correct?
Thanks.

Comment: Do all the women have to be sitting next to each other? Or does each one just need to be sitting next to another?

Comment: all women have to seat next to each other. I edited my question, sorry for that.

Comment: it means all together right ?

Comment: Yes, your analysis is correct. See @Harish’s answer for another way of arriving at the same conclusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

all women sitting next to each other I hope means all together.Then you are correct.

I will solve like

5 women considered as a unit . so 5 men + 1 women unit .arrange this first . then arrange women among themselves

$ 6! \times 5! $

Answer (score 1):

If all women need to be sitting next to each other, you're right. As a sanity check, you can check if your answer is less than 10! (it is). This doesn't prove that it's right, of course, but if it were bigger it would certainly be wrong.

Comment: Another quick question, Is it possible to feel that $6!\cdot5!$ is less then 10!? (without calculator)

Comment: 6! * 5! = 6! * (5*2) *(4*3)= 6! * 10 * 12. But 10! is 6! * 10 * (9*8*7) . even 9*8 = 72 is greater than 12 so 10! > 6!*5!

Comment: I don't think you can "feel" it without at least thinking a bit about it as Harish did.